# How to parse multidimensional json array

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to retreive some specific data from a json stored in my database.

Here is my fidle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5qZhsyddqJNej2NGj1x1hi/1

An exemple of a json string :

```
{
   "complexProperties":[
      {
         "properties":{
            "key":"Registred",
            "Value":"123456789"
         }
      },
      {
         "properties":{
            "key":"Urgency",
            "Value":"Total"
         }
      },
      {
         "properties":{
            "key":"ImpactScope",
            "Value":"All"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In this case I need to retreive the value of `Registred` which is `123456789`

Here is the request I tried to retreive first all value:

```
SELECT CAST(data AS jsonb)::json->>'complexProperties'->'properties' AS Registred FROM jsontesting
```

> Query Error: error: operator does not exist: text -> unknown

Comment: The first error is that you are storing JSON in a `text` column. That column should be defined as `jsonb`

Comment: The second error is that you store it in a JSON to begin with. The third error is that you don't store it as `{"Registered": 123456789}`.

Comment: It's from a proprietary software, I don't have hands on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON Path expression:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$.complexProperties[*].properties ? (@.key == "Registred").Value')
from jsontesting;
```

This returns a `jsonb` value. If you need to convert that to a `text` value, use `jsonb_path_query_first(...) #>> '{}'`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/9U-vBhJg)

Comment: Needed to add `CAST(data AS jsonb)` because my column is as VARCHAR

Comment: @executable: yes, annoying casts are required if you don't use the proper data type when defining the table.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that first flattens the JSON field (the `arrj` subquery) and then performs an old-school select. Using your `jsontesting` table -

```sql
select (j -> 'properties' ->> 'Value') 
from 
(
 select json_array_elements(data::json -> 'complexProperties') as j 
 from jsontesting
) as arrj
where j -> 'properties' ->> 'key' = 'Registred';
```

[Online example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hsJuUstXZvuh452pxe9R3v/1)